# What does ‘a one time deal‘ mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> All the extra nutrients result in an explosion in plant life. But since the addition of this food is usually **a one time deal**, the ecosystem cannot support all the extra flora.

What does "a one time deal" mean in this context?

Comment: Actually it means the same thing it means in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I might not be correct, but I think it means it is the one time and the only time depending on what context.